# How to get list of significant signals/lags in ccf plot using forecast package?

Tags: r, forecasting, cross-correlation

I made a cross-correlation plot using the forecast package.

There are a quite few lags/signals that are significant and I want to find out at what lag number they are at, considering that my range is -120 to 120. Is there some sort of function in forecast to create an output that will make a list kinda something like this:
[image]

There's an equivalent function in the tseries package called ccfvalues but I find that tseries is not as flexible as forecast.

Here's the code for the graph:

```
Ccf(diff(Site1V2OxygenWoNA$Oxygen), diff(Site1V2TempWoNA$Temp), type = "correlation", calc.ci = TRUE, level = 95, lag.max = 118, plot = TRUE, na.action = na.interp, main = "Site 1 OT")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you want is the `acf` element:

```
out <- ccf(diff(Site1V2OxygenWoNA$Oxygen), diff(Site1V2TempWoNA$Temp), type = "correlation", calc.ci = TRUE, level = 95, lag.max = 118, plot = TRUE, na.action = na.interp, main = "Site 1 OT")$acf[, , 1]
names(out) <- -floor(length(out) / 2):floor(length(out) / 2) # Adding lag names
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you!